# Как прокрутить скролбар вниз?

Tags: javascript

Я пишу online чат. Как сделать так, чтобы при большом количестве сообщений скролбар сам опускался в самый низ. Т.е. для того чтобы просмотреть новые сообщения пользователю не нужно было пролистывать скролбар вниз. 
Как автоматически опускать скролбар в самый низ элемента?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотреть, как это работает - http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/BSLXE/

**HTML**

```
<div id="chat">
    <p>Сообщение 1</p>
    <p>Сообщение 2</p>
    <p>Сообщение 3</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var posTop = $('#chat p:last').position().top;
$('#chat').animate({
    scrollTop: posTop
}, 1000);
```

---

**UPD**

Обновленная ссылка - http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/BSLXE/10/. Обновляйте переменную, после каждого скролла!

```
var lastEl = $('#chat p:last');
var posTop = lastEl.position().top;
function scrollBottom(i){
    $('#chat').append('<p>Новое сообщение ' + i +  '</p>');

    $('#chat').animate({
        scrollTop: posTop
    }, 500, function(){
        posTop += lastEl.height();
    });
}

var i = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(i > 8){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    i++;
    scrollBottom(i);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: работает, но только когда первый приходит сообщение. при приходе второго сообщения уже неправильно переменную posTop считает

Comment: Ну, так перепенную posTop надо обновлять каждый раз, когда появляется сообщение. Если вы ajax используете, то в :success/ajaxSuccess(), например. Она ведь не должна быть статической.

Comment: Она и не является статической. она каждый раз обновляется, когда приходит сообщение.

Comment: Дополнил в ответе

Answer (score 0):

А что если:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <div id="txt">
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="end"></div>
</div>
```

и в адресной строке `http://example.com/#end`

без js!

> при приходе второго сообщения уже
> неправильно...

на предмет этого проверьте!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте при загрузке чата и каждом обновлении следующий код:

```
el.scrollTop = Math.ceil(el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight);
```

Где el - это страница или элемент, где требуется все промотать вниз, а округление нужно для точности позиционирования на экранах с высоким разрешением.